# Switching Schemas Programatically in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am building a web app using asp.net mvc. My database is SQL server I have a schema for each of my clients and I need the same tables for each of the clients. What I want to achieve is show the data from the right table and schema when the client is logged in. Is there any way I could use the same table with the same structure but with different clients?

Example: I have 2 clients A and B in my DB I will have A.products, A.Orders, B.products and B.Orders. When the user accesses the app they will first login. then if they are user A the dashboard should show the products for client A and so on.

I have found some answers here but they are very old and I'm wondering if there is a better way to do things.

Comment: How are you making the SQL queries? Are you using an ORM (EF, Dapper, etc) or using ADO.NET?

Comment: I am currently using EF

Comment: Simplest way in my mind is to have a different login per client, and set that logins default schema. Even better, ensure the login only has access to that schema. This is also a good additional security layer. Then you don't need to actually mention the schema anywhere in your code or model.